# Java threading problem

Tags: java, multithreading, resume, suspend

I'm using multiple threads in my application. Basically I have a combo box and upon selecting Inbox, p1 resumes and p2 is suspended and upon selecting Send, p2 starts and p1 stops. Below is the code (I'm sure it's not perfect)

```
public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                if (combo.getText().equals("Inbox"))
                {
                    synchronized(p2) 
                    {
                        p2.cont = false;
                    }
                    table.removeAll();
                    synchronized(p1)
                    {
                        p1.cont = true;
                        p1.notify();
                    }
                }


                else if (combo.getText().equals("Sent"))
                {
                    synchronized(p2) 
                    {
                        p1.cont = false;
                    }
                    table.removeAll();
                    synchronized(p1)
                    {
                        p2.cont = true;
                        p2.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

and for P1 and P2 I have this inside their while loops:

```
synchronized (this) {
            while (cont == false)
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
        }
```

... As it is it's now working (I'm a beginner to threads). On pressing Sent in the combo box, I get an IllegalStateMonitorException. Could anyone help me solve the problem plz?

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
synchronized(p1)
{
    p2.cont = true;
    p2.notify();
}
```

You are doing `p2.notify()` when you haven't got a lock on `p2` (you must hold the monitor to call notify on it). Change `synchronized(p1)` to `synchronized(p2)`. Additionally, you need to reverse the other synchronized clause as well which is also faulty. So, as an example:

```
synchronized(p1) 
{
    p1.cont = false;
    // p1.notify(); <- do you need this here?
}
table.removeAll();
synchronized(p2)
{
    p2.cont = true;
    p2.notify();
}
```

Additionally, your other code is a bit wrong too, it's very bad practice to lock inside an entire loop, make it a bit more atomic.

```
while (!cont) {
    synchronized (this) {
       try {
           wait();
       } catch (Exception e) {
       }
    }
}
```

Additional optimisation, avoid `synchronised` if possible:

```
if (p1.cont) {
   synchronized(p1) 
   {
       p1.cont = false;
       // p1.notify(); <- do you need this here?
   }
}
table.removeAll();

if (!p2.cont) {
   synchronized(p2)
   {
       p2.cont = true;
       p2.notify();
   }
}
```

Make the cont field `volatile` here, and mirror for the other part of the if statement as appropriate.

Edit: looking back on this and battling with a concurrency bug I was recently facing, anyone implementing this pattern might face a problem with an infinite wait, if an object being locked & half-locked on is being looked at by the conditional of the while loop (this is because there is a gap where the state can change between evaluating the conditional and the imposition of the wait statement). In this case, place the synchronized block on the *outside* of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
                synchronized(p1)
                {
                    p2.cont = true;
                    p2.notify();
                }
```

You're synchronizing on `p1` but calling `notify()` on `p2`, which leads to the exception.

Answer (score -1):

You can't wait in awt event dispatch thread or else that will hold up your entire app.  Read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread

Also you shouldn't use raw threads unless you really know what you are doing.  Check out http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html and read up on [Executors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Comment: He's not waiting in the AWT thread. He's just calling notify(). Additionally, I'd recommend calling notifyAll() to make sure that the waiting thread gets notified.

Comment: By using synchronized anywhere in the EDT that can cause a wait.  Is that not true?

Comment: This is what guarded locks are about; their lock backs off to a half-lock while waiting. This allows another thread to grab the lock and then resume the other thread. Either way, if you use notify() or wait(), you *must* have a lock on the object. See http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/Threadnotify.htm for details.

Comment: Yes, but this is in the context of the EDT.  You are assuming modifyText can be called twice, which is false.

Comment: It can be called twice, as p1 and p2 should be locked by half-locks (assuming he modifies his code). Edited the post as there was a mistake (he needs to modify more code).